# IBrokers R - paper trading account orders

Tags: r, ibrokers

Is it possible to process trades to a paper account through the `IBrokers` package?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Make sure you use your login for the paper trading account.  Also, in recent TWS versions the default API port is 7497 to distinguish from the real account at 7496.  Of course, these can all be changed in the configure -> api -> settings dialog.

Note the default in IBrokers is 7496.

```
twsConnect(clientId = 1, host = 'localhost',
port = 7496, verbose = TRUE, timeout = 5,
filename = NULL, blocking=.Platform$OS.type=="windows")
```

So add a parameter `port = 7497` when you connect.